# Angularjs passing object as attrs to a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started learning angularjs recently, and no I'm trying the directives and i have this issue, I want to pass an object to the directive through an attribute then use its properties. My code is like this:
Directive :

```
app.directive("directiveOne", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'js/views/viewOne.html',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.promoDetail = attrs.promodetail;
        //scope.testAttr = attrs.testattr;

        scope.clickMe = function(){
          alert ('button clicked');
          console.log("button clicked!");
        }
    }
  }
})
```

viewOne.html

```
<div class="ui container" style="width: 800px; margin: 20px auto; background:url(../images/pic1.jpeg); background-position: center; background-size: cover; background-attachment:fixed; color: #f5f5f5; padding: 15px; text-align: justify ">
  <!-- <img src="../images/pic1.jpeg" alt="image untrouvable" style="width:100%; height:300px; position: absolute; z-index: -100;"> -->
  <h2>{{ promoDetail.title1 }} </h2>
  <h3> {{ promo.title2}} </h3>
    {{ testAttr}}
  <p>
    {{ promo.description }}
  </p>
  <button class="ui primary basic button" ng-click="clickMe()">SomeText{{ buttonText }}</button>
</div>
```

index.html

```
  <directive-one ng-repeat="promo in promos |limitTo : 3" promoDetail="{{ promo }}" testAttr="{{ promo.title1 }}" ></directive-one>
```

when I review the page in the browser the directive template doesn't show anything from the `promoDetail` attribute. I also tried console logging `promoDetail` it shows the data, but when I tried `console.log(promoDetail.title1)` it returns undefined. what's wrong with the code I wrote?

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as resolved, cheers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your attributes into the scope-object in your directive:

```
app.directive("directiveOne", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        promoDetails: '=',  // '@' = string, '=' = object, '&' = function
        testAttr: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'js/views/viewOne.html',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs){
        console.log(scope.promoDetail);
        console.log(scope.testAttr);

        scope.clickMe = function(){
          alert ('button clicked');
          console.log("button clicked!");
        }
    }
  }
})
```

In your html:

```
...promoDetail="promo" testAttr="{{promo.title1}}"...
```

But you don't need to pass the promo.title1 in an extra property, 'promo' is the whole object and is available in your directive. But if you wanna pass a string into your directive, write it like:

```
...testAttr="test"...
```

Now, in your property testAttr will be 'test', not the variable test.

Documentation: Under 'Isolating the Scope of a Directive' https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I did what you said still doesn't work, when I try `console.log(scope.promoDetail)` it returns undefined. In the html why remove th double curly braces around the promo?

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the variable to the directive through `scope`

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        promoDetail: '=',
        testAttr: '='
    },
```

Now in the html call the assign the values to the variable without curly brackets.

```
<directive-one ng-repeat="promo in promos |limitTo : 3" promoDetail="promo" testAttr="promo.title1">
```

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that the attributes names you write inside the scope of the directive is not exactly the same as the one you pass into it in the html. If you use CamelCase like I did `promoDetail="something"` in the scope you write it all in downCase.
directiveOne.js

```
app.directive("directiveOne", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      promodetail: '=',
      testattr: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'js/views/viewOne.html',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs){
        console.log(scope.promodetail.title1);
        console.log(scope.testattr);
        scope.clickMe = function(){
          alert ('button clicked');
          console.log("button clicked!");
        }
    }
  }
})
```

index.html

```
<directive-one ng-repeat="promo in promos |limitTo : 3" promoDetail="promo" testAttr="test"></directive-one>
```